# Conductive Inks

Tags: electricity

I would like to know a few examples of Conductive (Electrical) Inks which can either easily be synthesised or bought online (Low Cost) and also happen to be transparent.
Thanks

Comment: By conductive I mean electrically conductive.

Comment: I think its a case of choose any two. Cheap and conductive is possible, but not transparent. Conductive and transparent has been researched, but not cheap. You'd also struggle to synthesise these things yourself without access to specialised lab facilities

Comment: If you don't need a rigorously transparent/conductive ink, [PEDOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly%283,4-ethylenedioxythiophene%29) may work. It's often used mixed with polystyrenesulfonate (PSS) in an aqueous solution.

Answer (score 3):

As @NotNicolau states, choices are limited. [Indium-tin oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_tin_oxide) is transparent, though it does absorb a bit of light and its high index of refraction causes some reflective loss. However, it is usually applied by vapor deposition, sputtering etc.

[Nickel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DEEGYMM) and [silver conductive ink (paint)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OZATJ3A) is readily available for window defroster grid or printed circuit board repair and has a resistance of a few ohms per square, but it's opaque.

[Aquadag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquadag), a colloidal graphite paint, is inexpensive and has resistance ~ 1 kilohm per square, but is also is opaque.

That said, there *is* [ongoing research on graphene-based conductive inks](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/technical-documents/articles/technology-spotlights/graphene-inks-for-printed-electronics.html#ref). In a thin (perhaps monomolecular) layer, graphene is close to transparent. You might [buy](https://graphene-supermarket.com/) or make graphene or graphene oxide, disperse it in ethanol, apply it as ink and test if its conductive enough for your purposes.

You can also [buy In-Sn oxide coated PETE plastic](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1309).